# ssl_upgrade_error rabbitMQ

Tags: java, ssl, rabbitmq

I have sucessfully configurated RabbitMQ to accept TLS-Connections(Only TLS1.1 and TLS1.2)

now I have written a Java program which connects to the rabbitMQ-Server.

The server(10.0.0.120) and the 2 clients(10.0.0.121-122) are all running on an seperate RaspberryPI which almost same configuration

I can connect to the Server using openssl

```
root@10.0.0.122:~# openssl s_client -connect 10.0.0.120:5671
...
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA256
    Session-ID:     2D1E2F6CECA4DCB3D7403E9DEF9F9DEAADF5AC15298D6CA54120F26D70D5E4A7
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:     003C06F78281F23D8E2D7432E84B59EEABE586FA4472CF29259F8E7DAE4BD5F2F678A7F4FA27F9FBE6616481BAEEA131
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1422352831
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---

root@10.0.0.121:~# openssl s_client -connect 10.0.0.120:5671
...
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA256
    Session-ID:         B5538A83AE671DF2295632D02549C2E3059EED8DC73235DCE3D58FD69ABF7A62
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 86F3DDB68E5AB3796A9B762289AE7BD6D0E9A71CB549836D1A01C468180CAB98B9B819A1AF2255AE0BBF8B5911823EB8
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1422352895
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
```

both have the same java version

```
root@10.0.0.121:~# java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

root@10.0.0.122:~# java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

and on both is running the same jar file

```
root@10.0.0.121:~# md5sum rabbitReceive.jar
6df91e2e714341588908798f7e28fa10  rabbitReceive.jar

root@10.0.0.122:~# md5sum rabbitReceive.jar
6df91e2e714341588908798f7e28fa10  rabbitReceive.jar
```

when I start the JAR file on 10.0.0.122 (where it works!) I get this on the rabbitMQ server log

```
=INFO REPORT==== 27-Jan-2015::11:07:11 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.3709.0> (10.0.0.121:52944 -> 10.0.0.120:5671)
```

when I start the Jar file on 10.0.0.121 I get this on the rabbitMQ server log

```
=INFO REPORT==== 27-Jan-2015::11:08:06 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.3755.0> (10.0.0.122:37283 -> 10.0.0.120:5671)

=ERROR REPORT==== 27-Jan-2015::11:08:11 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.3755.0>:
 {ssl_upgrade_error,timeout}
```

and this exception in the Clients JVM

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1705)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:122                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             )
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Handshaker.java:909)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1423)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             java:1288)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             )
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHan                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             dler.java:129)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHan                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             dler.java:134)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:278)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             .java:617)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             .java:639)
    at rabbitMqTest.Test.main(Test.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             der.java:58)
```

Any Ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see, between the start of your jar and the error, there are exactly 5 seconds between.

By default, the ssl-handshake timeout is set to 5 seconds. Your problem is that the ssl handshake can't be done in the default 5 seconds.

You need to change the `NORMAL_TIMEOUT` and possible the `HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT` too at the top of `rabbit_reader.erl` to increase the timeout.

You can find the configuration-settings are described [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html).

Comment: there is no such file on my system

Comment: thank you! I found an option in the rabbitmq.config to increase the ssl-handshake timeout!

Comment: for future reference, these config settings are documented here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html